# SQL Select Same Table Multiple Sums

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to wrap my head round this issue and I am sure the answer exists here a million times but then I am not searching for the right question.

I have a huge sales table [SALES] and I am extracting

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.[ORDER ID], S1.SUPPLIER, SUM(S1.[ORDER TOTAL]) AS SUPPLIERTOTAL
FROM [SALES] S1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
     Select s2.[Order ID], S2.[Supplier], S2.[Supplier Colour], SUM(S2.[Order TOTAL]) AS COLOURTOTAL
FROM [SALES]
WHERE [SALES].[SALESDATE] Between '20160101' and '20170101'
    ) AS s2
ON s1.[Order ID] = s2.[Order ID]
```

I have thrown this code together as an illustration as I am not by my work PC at present.  My issue is that when I do get the re-select to work it produces the correct order value from the first select.

E.G  Lets say the manufacturer was Ford and the total value was 100000 over ten orders it returns the 100000 correctly however on the sub select it appears to take the total value and multiply it by the total number of rows in the table.  I am trying to work out what is going on with the data and query but cannot see the issue.

The only factor if its of influence is that the table has no primary key but as I am providing referential integrity with the join didn't believe that would be the case...

Anyone able to answer or come across this issue>

Comment: Whose `ORDER TOTAL` do you actually want to report here?  It looks like both tables have that column, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: As crazy as this may sound the reason why is that is that, that is what has been requested so that the total amount of the entire order per manufacturer shows up in one column then the categorised totals show up in another.  If its not clear as to the output expectation I can mock up an example of what they are hoping to see...

Comment: The query confuses me, because you are aggregating something in the subquery which never gets used in the outer query.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of guessing here, as the question is not too clear, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT S1.[ORDER ID], S1.SUPPLIER, SUM(S1.[ORDER TOTAL]) AS SUPPLIERTOTAL, SUM(S2.COLOURTOTAL) as COLOURTOTAL
FROM [SALES] S1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
     Select s2.[Order ID], S2.[Supplier], S2.[Supplier Colour], S2.[Order TOTAL] AS COLOURTOTAL
FROM [SALES]
WHERE [SALES].[SALESDATE] Between '20160101' and '20170101'
    ) AS s2
ON s1.[Order ID] = s2.[Order ID]
GROUP BY S1.[ORDER ID], S1.SUPPLIER
```